# Accessibility broken with Preview.app in OS X 10.8.4?

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility

We have an application that integrates with different programs (among which is the Preview.app) using accessibility. We use the `AXUIElementSetAttributeValue` function to programmatically select some text in a PDF document using the `kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute`. This used to work fine but suddenly stopped on my Mac (nothing seems to happend). My co-worker doesn't have the issue so after trying to figure out the difference I remembered that I had just updated to OS X 10.8.4 while he hasn't. I then read about this update and among the features and fixes was the following:

*Improves VoiceOver compatibility with text in PDF documents*

This indicates to me that they have fiddled with the area where I am having the issue. My question is now weather this is simply a bug or if it is by design. In the case of the latter, what am I supposed to use in stead?

PS. We tried also setting the selection range using the Accessibility Inspector found under Developer tools in Xcode and it works fine in 10.8.2 but not in 10.8.4, which further indicates that this might be a bug.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are getting at here. While VoiceOver is great, the one major hole with it is that it doesn't have any real support for PDFs. People who are blind, or just use VO, have to access PDFs another way, either by getting help from somebody or using another OS

Comment: We are not using VoiceOver at all, but rather the accessibility framework to do our own stuff with PDF documents. The reason that I mention VO is that it would seem that when they were tweaking it for better compatibility they accidently broke some of the accessibility attributes in Preview.

Comment: I am still confused by what you are getting at. Are you just trying to select text in a PDF, and piggy backing on the fact of the quoted line? If so, this is not an accessibility question. From what I understand, the level of accessibility support on osx is akin if you took a PDF on windows, did a select all and pasted into notepad. Preview now has the accessibility of Acrobat on Windows did back in pre-2004/5

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what the confusion is about. Just to underline, we are not using VoiceOver at all, for anything. We are using the Accessibility framework to integrate with a number of applications, including Preview. We use accessibility to extract text from applications (for instance from a PDF document in Preview), process this text in some way and highlight which text is being processed. This "highlight" is actually a selection which is set programmatically using the `kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute`. It is this last bit which has stopped working in 10.8.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug. I just installed the developer preview of OS X 10.8.5 and the issue has been resolved here. In the change-log it also says that some of the changes in this version regard "PDF viewing and Accessibility".